# How to get all the sharepoint 2013 site groups using C# client side object model

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-server, csom

How to get all the SharePoint 2013 Site Groups using C# Client Side Object Model

1. I am using VS 2013 on my laptop and SP 2013 is on the network
2. I read that I have to use Credentials or equivalent but dont know how

   ```
   namespace ConsoleApplication5
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               // ClientContext - Get the context for the SharePoint Site
               // SharePoint site URL - http://servername/sites/CSOM
               ClientContext clientContext = new
               ClientContext("http://sp2013/");
               // Get the SharePoint web
               Web web = clientContext.Web;
               // Get all the site groups
               GroupCollection groupColl = web.SiteGroups;
               clientContext.Load(groupColl);
               // Execute the query to the server
               clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

               foreach (Group group in groupColl)
               {
               // Display the group name
               Console.WriteLine(group.Title);
               }
               Console.ReadLine();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by Passing NetworkCredentials as below

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp2013/");
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password","Domain");
```

Comment: I did try that option now it gives me 403 forbidden error and this account is the site collection administrator and also belongs to the owner group also i noticed that in SP2013 I have enabled dual authentication would that be a problem ?

Comment: It does not matter if I am developing on my client machine ? , the same code works in SP2010 and does not work in SP2013 that is very strange .I am not able to get the c# code to display even the title

Comment: It seems like issue related to your server configuration

Comment: Ok here is what i found out sp2010 if I give the site collection root , then it returns an error , sp2013 i created a subsite and i gave the url for the subsite and it still gives me the 403 forbidden error , i also ran the same code on dev box same error  clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testuser1", "Password1","mydomain"); <--- is this right ?

Comment: it is just an analogy

Comment: I log on to dev box and I execute this command Get-SPSite http://itlab |  Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb | Select -ExpandProperty Groups |Select {$_.ParentWeb.Url}, Name and it shows all the groups

Answer (score 1):

to answer my own question SP2010 is by default windows authentication and SP2013 is claims based the below code worked for me

```
       ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp2013:27898");
        clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        GroupCollection groupColl = web.SiteGroups;
        UserCreationInformation userInfo = new UserCreationInformation();

        clientContext.Load(groupColl);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (Group group in groupColl)
        {
            // Display the group name
            Console.WriteLine(group.Title);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();





    }


    static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possible issue may be that SharePoint site will have different authentication configured.

Use below code and replace the **`authenticationMethod`** with your authentication method and it will work.

In my case **`authenticationMethod`** was **`NTLM`**

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
    myCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "authenticationMethod", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
    clientContext.Credentials = myCache;
    Group grp = null;
    GroupCollection groupColl = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
    clientContext.Load(groupColl,
    groups => groups.Include(
    group => group.Title,
    group => group.Id));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (Group siteGroup in groupColl)
    {
        console.writeLine(siteGroup.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to export these groups into an excel or csv file?